# есть хеш 256 и я знаю частичный ответ. как можно помочь разхешировать хеш?

Tags: sha256

например 2244821EA42CCA3E9616E469CF844F3C128D27A1E11210733185A485142AE27B
ответ 0.34890589106949826944310761778169271091277267578497638410874574
можно ли как то создать команду? чтобы она перебирала 65 символов? то есть ответ всегда 0. и остальные 63 числа?

Comment: То есть вы хотите перебрать 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 вариантов? Не уверен, что вы сможете дождаться...

Answer (score 2):

### Коротко: нет.

---

Одно из [требований](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) хэш-функций, это **сопротивление поиску прообраза**. Говоря простым языком: нет (на данный момент для SHA-256) обратной функции или алгоритма, которые могли получать исходные данные по полученому хэшу.

Но, всё же, бывают [атаки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0) для более устаревших хэш-функций, направленные на поиски такого прообраза.

И, как отметили в комментариях, можно перебрать всевозможные значения, но на это уйдёт слишком много времени.